# A Sql query writing with linq (inner select linq)

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to write the SQL query with Entity Framework using Linq. I could not write it because I am at the initial level. Can you help me?

```
SELECT *,rowcnt = COUNT(*) over() 
from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserName desc) AS sira, * 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE UserName LIKE '%de%' or Name LIKE '%de%' or Surname LIKE '%de%' or Passwordd LIKE '%de%') as u
WHERE sira BETWEEN 0 and 20 
group by u.ID,u.UserName,u.Name,u.Surname,u.Passwordd,u.sira
```

Comment: I am sory sql query : SELECT *,rowcnt = COUNT(*) over() from
                (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserName desc) AS sira, *FROM Users
                WHERE UserName LIKE '%de%' or Name LIKE '%de%' or Surname LIKE '%de%' or Passwordd LIKE '%de%') as u WHERE sira BETWEEN 0 and 20 
                         group by u.ID,u.UserName,u.Name,u.Surname,u.Passwordd,u.sira

Comment: You can just click the edit button and make the changes yourself. If you want to format code, simply indent the text with 4 whitespaces.

Comment: Hi @Emine, I have edited your question, please check the SQL query, is it correct? And can you tell us whether your application is an Asp.net core application or a tranditional .Net Framework application, and whether you are using EF or EF core? Then, do you mean you want to change the SQL query to LINQ Query statement?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your corrections. As you mentioned, I am using asp.net (core), entityframework core. I wrote the code yesterday. I wanted to share it with you. I will be glad if you check.

Comment: Users.Where(x => x.UserName == "e"|| x.Name =="e"|| x.Surname=="e")
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.UserName).Select(p => new {
   ID = p.ID,
   UserName = p.UserName,
   Name = p.Name,
   Surname=p.Surname,
   Pasword=p.Passwordd,
   a = Users.Where(x => x.UserName == "e"|| x.Name =="e"|| x.Surname=="e").Count()
   }).Skip(1).Take(2).ToList()